# Maximize function on orthogonal matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, maxima-minima, orthogonal-matrices

Consider the function $f$ from the set of $n \times n$ real matrices taking $A=(a_{ij})$ to $f(A):= \prod_{(i,j) \neq (k,l)}(a_{ij}-a_{kl}) $.

**Edit:** Note that $f(A) \ge 0$ for all $A$, since grouping pairs we have
$$f(A):=(-1)^{\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{2}}\prod_{(i,j) \lt_ {lex} (k,l)}(a_{ij}-a_{kl})^2$$
and $ n^2(n^2-1) \equiv 0 \, \text{mod} \, 4$ for all $n$, **end edit.**

Is there a way to compute $M:=\text{max}\{  f(A)   : A A^{t}=I  \}$ ?. I know that, since $A$ orhogonal implies $\mid a_{ij} \mid \leq 1$ for all $ 1\leq i,j \leq n $, we have that $2^{2 {n^2 \choose 2}}=2^{n^2(n^2-1)}$ is a trivial upper bound on M, but for example if $n=2$ we have that actually $M=0$ because every $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix has at least two equal entries.

So if we can't compute $M$ can we at least give a better upper bound?.

---

Following your advice. I estimated $M$ using random orthogonal matrices for $n \le 6$. Here are the results I've got:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & \text{# of orth. Matrices} & \text{Estimated} \, M  \\ \hline
2 & \infty & 0 \\ \hline
3 & 5\times 10^4 & 1.13762 \times 10^{-17} \\ \hline
4 & 5\times 10^4 & 3.10228 \times 10^{-80} \\ \hline
5 & 1 \times 10^3 & 5.71162 \times 10^{-248} \\ \hline
6 & 1\times 10^3 & 2.80541 \times 10^{-588}\\ \hline.
\end{array}

for example this is what the graphic for $n=3$ looks like:

[image: simulation]

So it seems that $M$ is much more smaller than the trivial bound. Does anyone has an idea of how to construct a formal proof?. I'll be offering a bounty as soon as is allowed.

Comment: you're right I'm off by a sing see the edit

Comment: In your example $f(A) =(-1)^{6}((x-y)(x-z)(x-w)(y-z)(y-w)(z-w))^2 \geq 0$ and in general $(-1)^{n^2(n^2-1)/2} f(A) \geq 0 $ for all $A$.

Comment: Have you done some simulation?

Comment: No, I don't know how to generate random orthogonal matrices, but it's a good idea thanks.

Comment: You can generate them by exponentiating skew symmetric matrices

Comment: Thanks for your help  @user251257 and @ Max, What do you think of the results?.

Comment: I don't understand the graph. What's on the horizontal axis?

Comment: I made a sequence of 50000 orthogonal matrices $ \{ A_n : n \leq 50000 \}$ and graphed the points $\{(n,f(A_n)) : n \leq 50000 \}$

Comment: You can get an upper bound of something like $2^{-n^4/2+cn^4}$ from $|a_{ij}|\leq 1,$ see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210229/maximum-of-the-vandermonde-determinant-minimum-of-the-logarithmic-energy/210348

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this was related to the so called Fekete problem, that definitely gives us better bounds using the roots of the derivate of the Legendre polynomial. For example, it gives $M_{3} \leq 7.0320 \times 10^{-11}$, $M_{4} \leq  1.3403 \times 10^{-48}$ and $M_{5} \leq 1.5823 \times 10^{-138} $. That's still far from the results of the simulation but way better than the trivial bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bound like $e^{-\frac{n^4}{2}\ln n}$ by elementary means (AM-GM) by exploiting the orthogonality, but it's still far from the numerical results you have (and somewhat worse than the computation with Legendre polynomials, although it should be better in the long run according to Dap's comment).

By AM-GM
$$f(A)^{\frac{1}{\binom{n^2}{2}}}\le \frac{\sum_{(i,j)<(k,l)}(a_{ij}-a_{kl})^2}{\binom{n^2}{2}}=\frac{(n^2-1)\sum_{(i,j)} a_{ij}^2-2\sum_{(i,j)<(k,l)}a_{ij}a_{kl}}{\binom{n^2}{2}}.$$
Now $\sum a_{ij}^2=|A|^2=n$. As for the second term
$$2\sum_{(i,j)<(k,l)} a_{ij}a_{kl}= \Big(\underbrace{\sum_{(i,j)} a_{ij}}_{S(A)}\Big)^2 -\sum_{(i,j)} a_{ij}^2$$
and therefore
$$f(A)^{\frac{1}{\binom{n^2}{2}}}\le \frac{n^3-S(A)}{\binom{n^2}{2}}.$$
From e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41070/sum-of-coefficients-of-an-orthogonal-matrix) we have that for an orthogonal matrix $A$
$$|S(A)|=\left|\sum a_{ij}\right|\le n\qquad (*)$$
and thus
$$f(A)^{\frac{1}{\binom{n^2}{2}}}\le \frac{n^3+n}{\binom{n^2}{2}}=\frac{2(n^2+1)}{n(n^2-1)}\approx \frac{2}{n}.$$
Taking the logarithm
$$\ln(f(A))\le \binom{n^2}{2} \ln\left(\frac{2(n^2+1)}{n(n^2-1)}\right)\approx -\frac12 n^4\ln n. $$
For instance for $n=5$ we obtain $1.11\times 10^{-109}$ and for $n=6$ we obtain $4.14\times 10^{-286}$.

$(*)$ This is obtained by applying Cauchy-Schwartz in a slick way and is slightly better than applying it in the more obvious way, which gives $n^{3/2}$. This is not really relevant in the asymptotics above though.

Comment: My interpretation of the numerical results was that $M^{1/{ n^2 \choose 2}}$ had to be pretty close to $1/n$  (and may be a bit below) , getting  to $2/n$ is really good,thanks.